# Why can't I set the height of the navigation bar in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I was wondering how to code a sticky `navbar` using HTML, CSS and JS. I have created sticky navigation without jQuery, but the `height` function is not working properly. Can anybody suggest me how can I call this `height` function? How can I find the `height` in pure JavaScript?

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  'use strict';
  var c, currentScrollTop = 0;
  var navbar = document.querySelector(".nav");
  window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
    var a = (document.documentElement && document.documentElement.scrollTop) || document.body.scrollTop;
    var b = navbar.hight();
    currentScrollTop = a;
    if (c < currentScrollTop && a > b + b) {
      navbar.addClass("scrollUp");
    } else if (c > currentScrollTop && !(a <= b)) {
      navbar.removeClass("scrollUp");
    }
    c = currentScrollTop;
  });
});
```

```html
<nav>
  <div class="container">
    <a href="#" id="brand">Brand</a>
    <button>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="navbar-menu">
      <li>
        <a href="#">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">About</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Team</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Timeline</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Conact</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: hight != height; I think you have a typo in your code

Comment: Is the nav bar at the top of the page, or does it have a top margin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`nav` is not a class. It is an HTML tag. Hence, `document.querySelector(".nav")` will return an empty node list.

**Change**

```
document.querySelector(".nav")

var b = navbar.height();
```

**to**

```
document.querySelector("nav")

var b = navbar.clientHeight;
// or
var height = navbar.offsetHeight;
```

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  'use strict';
  var c, currentScrollTop = 0;
  var navbar = document.querySelector("nav");
  window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
    var a = (document.documentElement && document.documentElement.scrollTop) || document.body.scrollTop;
    var b = navbar.clientHeight
    currentScrollTop = a;
    if (c < currentScrollTop && a > b + b) {
      navbar.addClass("scrollUp");
    } else if (c > currentScrollTop && !(a <= b)) {
      navbar.removeClass("scrollUp");
    }
    c = currentScrollTop;
  });
});
```

```html
<nav>
  <div class="container">
    <a href="#" id="brand">Brand</a>
    <button>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
    </button>

    <ul class="navbar-menu">
      <li>
        <a href="#">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">About</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Team</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Timeline</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Conact</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: nav is not an attribute - you can call it either a "tag" or an "element".